# how to make correct timing trigger in google apps script, please check my code line

Tags: google-apps-script

## I am very new to GAS. The already created script (paragraph 3) I need it to be run everyday, every 3 hours, at a specific time at 0:30 -> 3:30 -> 6:30 -> 9:30 -> 12:30-> 15:30-> 18:30-> 21:30

This is upper part of the code. Cannot "combine" below 3 codes into one

```
function createOpenTrigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("#what should I input here or leave blank????")
.forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
.onOpen()
.create();
}

function createTimeTriggerAtSpecificHourMinute() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger("what should I input here or leave blank????")
.timeBased(00:00)
.everyHour(3)
.nearMinute(30)
.everyDays(1)
.inTimezone("Asia/Tokyo")
.create();
}


function takeSnapShot() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SOURCE');
const snap = mainSheet.getRange("A1:Q26").getDisplayValues();
....
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to schedule your `takeSnapShot()` function to run  every three hours beginning at 00:30.

Using the sample code you have supplied you can replace your `createOpenTrigger()` and `createTimeTriggerAtSpecificHourMinute()` functions with something like this.

```
function setFirstCall(){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('setRecurrence')
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(0)
        .nearMinute(30)
        .inTimezone('Asia/Tokyo')
        .create();
}
```

This will trigger a one-off call to happen near 00:30 the next day. . After running, the trigger will delete itself but will schedule a function `setRecurrence()` to run. So next you need to create the recurring function.

```
function setRecurrence(){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('takeSnapShot')
        .timeBased()
        .everyHours(3)
        .create();
}
```

GAS doesn't allow scheduling for an 'exact' minute (there's a +/- 15min accuracy) however the recurrence should be for the same minute, i.e. if the first trigger runs in the 27th minute then every iteration after should be in the 27th minute.

Hopefully that helps.

---

#### References:

- [TriggerBuilder.timeBased()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timebased)
- [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: @AboveThemess can you give any error info?